# SAPI speech recognition training

Tags: c#, sapi

I want to make application which can recognize non-English words and I understand I have train SAPI in order to do that.

But how to do that ? I want to train my program to recognize non-English words and when I transfer it to another computer that it still recognizes these words and user on another computer can add other words.

Comment: Please don't put "C#" in your question title just to categorize the question. We use tags for that on [so].

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/222/), it discusses Speach Recongition and the [SRGS](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/) specification for saving Grammers. This [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723634%28VS.85%29.aspx) discusses grammer format tags which include a `LANGID` tag